# Algorithm for multiplication in finite field

Tags: finite-fields

I am trying to understand multiplication in finite fields. I have understood the usual multiplication method for multiplying two polynomials in a finite field. But I am unable to understand the algorithm using arrays, a portion of which from the training notes is attached. Also I have not understood the underlied step in the attached photo. Shifting of cells for multiplication by x is clear....but I have not understood the process if this is not the case. Any help towards understanding this concept would be appreciated [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMtRC.jpg)

Comment: It's going to save a lot of guesswork for Readers if you include some details of what you *do* understand.  Asking Readers to parse "training notes" and infer what part of finite field multiplication is clear and what part is unclear is a burden.

Comment: In the attached photograph, I have understood the steps upto the text "what happens if this is not the case". I want to understand the algorithm for multiplication of polynomials in finite field using array method

Comment: The picture shows an example of multiplication, but does not include the value of $f(x)$ as an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Z \bmod 3$.  See [this brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to posting mathematical notation here.

Comment: $f(x)$ as an irreducible polynomial is given in the second last step as $x^3-x^2+1$

Comment: Request also explain the third last underlined step

Comment: From cd=$2x^3+x^2+x+(f(x))$ how do we get cd=$2x^3+x^2+x-2f(x)+(f(x))$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92053/discussion-between-hardmath-and-sak).

Comment: The Question currently lacks context.  Have a look at this previous Question, [Left-multiplication of a finite field element - Matrix representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564093/left-multiplication-of-a-finite-field-element-matrix-representation) for a closely related discussion.  Addition with elements represented by arrays/components is very straightforward.